# How do I use a SSL .cert file with JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

My dev server needs to connect to another dev server's SOAP API, it uses https, I was given a .cert file to use with it.  How can I set that to be used using JAX-WS?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to import is to simply add the (self-signed) certificate to your local CA (Certificate Authorities) file:

```
keytool -import -alias devserver -file certfile.cert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Alternatives are to create a new keystore file, and specify the system property javax.net.ssl.trustStore

BTW, on most JDKs, the default passphrase for the 'cacerts' trustfile is 'changeit'.

To check that the certificate was added, you can use the following command:
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts -alias devserver

You also need to make sure that the URL which is used in webservices matches the 'CN' (Common Name) of the certificate.